# SwiftUI: popover + sheet in different hierarchies problem

Tags: swift, swiftui

I experience a problem of presenting a popover and then trying to present a sheet. The sheet is unable to be presented.

I have prepared a short code that displays two buttons

1. The first one presents a popover over itself ("Click this button")
2. The second one presents a sheet ("Then this button")

## Steps to reproduce

--- Reproducible on an iPad ---

1. Click the first button, a popover is presented
2. Directly click the second button while the popover is being visible.
   (without dismissing the popover any other way)
   State: The popover is dismissed, but the sheet is not being presented. And it is impossible to present it using the second button. The popover button still works though.

### Error

The following message is being printed to the console:

```
[Presentation] Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x10bc13cf0> 
on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerV10AppBuilder8RootView_: 0x105a093f0>
(from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerV10AppBuilder8RootView_: 0x105a093f0>) 
which is already presenting <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x10ba170a0>.
```

## Code

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyView: View {
    @State var showSheet: Bool = false
    
    struct SomeDeepView: View {
        @State var showPopover: Bool = false
        var body: some View {
            Button {
                showPopover = true
            } label: {
                Text("Click this button")
            }
            .popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                Text("Popover content")
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 64) {
            
            SomeDeepView()
            
            Button {
                showSheet = true
            } label: {
                Text("Then this button")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            Text("Sheet content")
        }
        .frame(width: 500, height: 500, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

## My thoughts

MyView shoudn't care about the internal stuff of SomeDeepView.
Also, SomeDeepView shouldn't care much about its exterior/parents.
Yet, we can't show a popover and a sheet at the same time. I would accept this knowing that the framework would handle this and wouldn't break. However, it does break.
Unexpected side effect: by changing showSheet is not able to display the sheet anymore.

Any thoughts, ideas are very welcome.
Thank you

Edit1: I don't consider toggle() as an effective sulution as it introduces another bug. You would need to press the button multiple times before it would react.

Comment: I've same issue, any solution by the far?

Comment: Same problem here, thanks for the code snippet and steps to reproduce, reported this to Apple -> 'FB11991898 Sheet does not appear when triggered while a popover is visible'.

Comment: The only (extremly ugly) workaround I found so far is to make sure that I dismiss the popover manually before setting the sheet-presenting state variable or to delay setting it for a moment via DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter.

Comment: @RalfEbert stupid question, Where is the report? I've the same issue. I've considered disabling the state as solution, however, DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter is not possible since the fullScreenCover cannot be set with it.

Comment: I also reported this as FB12078831 copied here: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5597349300666368

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a sheet and an alert. The point is, that SwiftUI can only present one modal at a time. The showSheet flag is inappropriate to check whether or not the sheet is actually still presented: when it's set to false it still takes some time until the sheet is not presented anymore (because of the animation I suppose). I solved this within the view by introducing an additional flag indicating the sheet is still presented. This flag is set to true/false within the `onAppear` and `onDismiss` sections of the sheet. When calculating the flag for the alert (calculated property) I take this additional flag into account.

Hopefully this will be solved in future versions of SwiftUI.

Comment: Could you post a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

```
if showPopover == false
{
   ShowSheet = true
}
```

this will only try to show sheet if the popover is already dismissed.  and on second click of sheet button sheet will show.

Comment: Did you tested this? Also, did you read the other answer and the comments? the default behavior is too late for this to  work. We rather prefer a full test code to see the result that works as you suggested.

Comment: Take the code of the OP, modify it, test it and publish your result with your development environment.

Comment: This will not work because MyView doesn't have access to SomeDeepView.showPopover. SomeDeepView may also reside in a different module with closed source code. So checking showPopover would not work.