# Sheet and Menu conflict with each other

Tags: swiftui

In the following example, there is a SwiftUI Menu and a Button that triggers a sheet. If you press the button while the menu is visible, this can cause the following error and then the button will be without function, giving the following error log (it might take a few tries):

```
2023-03-02 12:01:59.850609+0100 SheetButtonDemo[50295:6802586] [Presentation] Attempt to present <_TtGC7SwiftUI29PresentationHostingControllerVS_7AnyView_: 0x124815200> on <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x10c809200> (from <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVS_7AnyViewVS_12RootModifier__: 0x10c809200>) which is already presenting <_UIContextMenuActionsOnlyViewController: 0x107d0bf20>.
```

This seems to be a bug in SwiftUI, I reported this as FB12026200.

It is similar to this one: [SwiftUI: popover + sheet in different hierarchies problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425496/swiftui-popover-sheet-in-different-hierarchies-problem)

In the meantime: is there a good workaround to prevent this issue?

Example code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet = false
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 100) {
            Button("Show Sheet") {
                self.showSheet = true
            }
            Menu {
                Button("Action") {
                    print("Hello")
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Menu")
            }

        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, content: {
            Text("Sheet")
        })
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Image of the bug in action:

[image]

Comment: I submitted FB12078831 about this, copied here http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5597349300666368 I just added a note to reference your FB12026200 saying it also affects `Menu`

Answer (score 2):

It seems adding `.id(UUID())` to the menu works as a hotfix

```
Menu {
    //
} label: {
    Text("Label")
}
.id(UUID())
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but a `asyncAfter` around the sheet-presenting action seems to do the trick:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    self.showSheet1 = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following test code works well for me, on MacOS 13.3, using Xcode 14.3 beta, tested on real ios 16.3 devices (not Previews), and macCatalyst.
It could be different on older systems.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showSheet1 = false
    @State var showSheet2 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 100) {
            Button("Show Sheet 1") {
                showSheet1 = true
            }
            Menu {
                Button("Show Sheet 2") {
                    showSheet2 = true   // <-- here
                }
            } label: {
                // -- here, not a Button for testing
                Text("Menu")
                // Image(systemName: "filemenu.and.selection")
                // Button("Menu") { showSheet1 = true } // not usefull
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet1) {
            Text("Sheet 1")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet2) {
            Text("Sheet 2")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, my example snippet was a bit misleading, I realize that a Button as label for Menu is a bit unusual. Although that's not the problem, I can reproduce the problem with just a simple sheet-presenting-button and a Menu with a text label, too, both on iOS devices and simulator.

Comment: Both your old and your new code work well for me on the system I mentioned.
 When I press the button while the menu is visible, I do not get any errors.
 Your issue could very well be due to using an older system (ios/xcode/...).

Comment: Is that mean they fixed this issue ?, there is other kind of issue if you open sheet then you open the menu , when the menu still open tap on close button to dismiss sheet it usually won't work, I need to test this issue on Xcode 14.3, I think both issues releted to each other.

Comment: I can confirm the issue mention,  it fixed on iOS 16.4 and Xcode 14.3
but doesn't fixed on any version before iOS 16.4

Answer (score 0):

Menu and popover don't prevent from interacting with views beneath.

So if you tap another button to present a modal, while a menu or a popover is being presented, it'll cause this bug.

that is also why this code works

```
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
    self.showSheet1 = true
}
```